# Setting initial value in Spring form:select

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have an entity Order that contains another entity OrderType, as follows:

```
public class Order {

    private int id;
    private Date requestDate;
    private OrderType orderType;
}

public class OrderType {

    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

I have a JSP page where the user can edit an existing order to change the date or type:

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="order">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Order Type:</td>
            <td><form:select path="orderType"><form:options items="${orderTypes}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" /></form:select></td>
            <td><form:errors path="orderType" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td><form:input path="requestDate" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="requestDate" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

My controller is quite straightforward:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getOrder(@PathVariable("id") short id, Map<String, Object> map) throws ParseException {

    Order order = orderService.getOrder(id);

    List<OrderType> orderTypes = OrderTypeService.getAllOrderTypes();

    map.put("order", order);
    map.put("orderTypes", orderTypes);

    return "EditOrder";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editOrder(@PathVariable("id") short id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("order") Order order, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "EditOrder";
    } else {

        order.setId(id);

        orderService.updateOrder(order);

        return "redirect:/orders/";
    }
}
```

My problem is that when the JSP page loads, the drop-down is always set to the first item in the list, not the correct one. The rest of the page works fine (i.e. the correct value is persisted to the database upon form submission and spring validation is working fine).

If I change `<form:select path="orderType">` to `<form:select path="orderType.id">`, the drop-down gets set to the correct value but this gives me an error upon form submission as orderType is null. I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: It probably won't work, but you can try adding an `equals` (and corresponding `hashCode`) method to `OrderType` that will use the two fields to determine equality. Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @geoand the answer was to add hashCode and equals to the OrderType class:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```